# improve "search under cursor" (gf) in vim

Tags: vim

I'm reading Verilog code where I would like to open `unit1.vs` but the code contains:

```
unit1 unit1_instance {...}
```

I can do this by adding:

```
includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\(.*\)','\1.vs','i')
```

in vimrc and using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

I now have another `unit2.sdpv` which is instantiated like unit1. How can I extend `includeexpr` to search for `file.vs` and `file.sdpv`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `suffixesadd` instead of `includeexpr`:

```
:set suffixesadd=.vs,.sdpv
```

Comment: I've read a bunch of questions and answers online for this functionality, and most of the questions were really searching for `suffixesadd` while most of the answers were complicated solutions using `includeexpr`. Kudos for the dead-simple solution.